# How to include maven repository with id in gradle?

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to use [SimpleNativeHooks](https://github.com/repeats/SimpleNativeHooks) in my kotlin gradle project. I use the kotlin gradle dsl, but SimpleNativeHooks can not be found and downloaded. The error I get is:

```
    :KJ:launch:test: Could not find org.repeats.simplenativehooks:simplenativehooks:0.0.1.
    Required by:
        project :KJ:launch
    
    Possible solution:
     - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

The code I am currently using for the repo is:

```kotlin
dependencyResolutionManagement {
  repositories{
    maven {
      url = java.net.URI("https://raw.github.com/repeats/SimpleNativeHooks/maven-export/")
    }
  }
}
```

But on the github README, the maven example includes a few others as well. I'm wondering if the reason I'm getting an error in my gradle build is because I haven't properly converted that maven code into gradle, maybe because I missed some of those fields (like the repo id, which I don't know how to include in gradle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This URL is not a fair maven repository (it returns 400: Invalid request after 301: Permanent redirect), so you need to give Gradle a hint, where to look for artifacts metadata - in this case, there is [pom.xml](https://raw.github.com/repeats/SimpleNativeHooks/maven-export/pom.xml) in the root :

```kotlin
maven {
    url = uri("https://raw.github.com/repeats/SimpleNativeHooks/maven-export/")
    metadataSources {
        mavenPom()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you test this? did it work for you? It still hasn't worked for me

Comment: nevermind, it works now. For an unknown reason it did not work in settings.gradle where all my other repositories are declared, but it did work in the regular buildscript

Comment: 400, is because github (once) restricted directory access, but it works with files: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/repeats/SimpleNativeHooks/maven-export/pom.xml